After set targetSdk = 34, Activity in background can't receive update from foreground service
I have a Timer app. Use Foreground service to record time duration. This foreground service has a mutablelivedata that will postvalue when the countdown goes to zero. And in MainActiviy I observe this mutablelivedata, if get any update will save the record to the database.
Everything is fine until I set the targetSdk from 33 to 34.
Now if I leave the app to the background, the MainActivity can't get any update from foreground service until I open this activity again. But if  targetSdk = 33. I can get the update. So what should I do to migrate from 33 to 34. Thanks.

Personally, I wouldn't have used a MutableLiveData but rather a LocalBroadcast so that you can register from your MainActivity and receive updates from your service.
And your problem could be a background restriction, but you won't have this problem with the LocalBroadcast.

Thanks for your answer. I agree with you about the background restriction. I will try to use the LocalBroadcast to see how it goes. But I can't find a specific explanation about this restriction through Google. Could you give me more details?

Since android 14, there have been new background restrictions, you can check if you are impacted in the case of using foreground service.
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/behavior-changes-14
In terms of good practice, when sharing data between services and activities, it's best to use a broadcast, etc... a fairly reliable method.
You can find some here:
https://medium.com/the-sixt-india-blog/ways-to-communicate-between-activity-and-service-6a8f07275297

Thanks for your comment again. I took your advice. It's working. I will read the medium blog you mentioned.
